# Setting an Android Button visible after a certain period of time?

Tags: java, android, button

I have a button that I don't want to be clickable until a certain amount of time has run (say, 5 seconds?) I tried creating a thread like this

```
    continueButtonThread =  new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(5000);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
            }

            continueButton.setVisibility(0);                
        }
    };

    continueButtonThread.start();
```

But I can't modify the setVisibility property of the button within a different thread. This is the error from the LogCat:

10-02 14:35:05.908: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14400): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Any other way to get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you can touch views of your activity only in UI thread. you can do it by using `runOnUiThread` function. I would like to suggest you to use

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000)`
```

Answer (score 3):

You must update your view from UI-thread. What you are doing is you are updating from non-ui-thread.

Use

```
contextrunOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
```

or use handler and signalize `hand.sendMessage(msg)` when you think is right time to update the view visibility

```
 Handler hand = new Handler()        
        {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                /// here change the visibility
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method from the `View` class (A `Button` is a child of `View`)

Answer (score 0):

here is simple answer i found

```
Button button = (Button)findViewBYId(R.id.button);
button .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
button .postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        button .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}, 7000);
```